# Trimming collection used for calculation distance

Tags: java, algorithm

I have data collection where every record has information about speed of vehicle and time when this record was taken. Time difference between every record is various and it is about 300 ms. I use this collection to calculate travelled distance. I would like to trim this collection without too much loss of accuracy of calculation. Is there any algorithm for it?

I tried to write simple algorithm that deleted record if record does not differed from previous one by at least X %. This algorithm is not working well. For example when I used algorithm with 3% and 4% trimming, number of records was same but calculated distance differed by 40m on 500m distance, where 4% was more accurate.

EDIT: Changes on Benjamin algorithm:

I have time when record was collected so I need 3 records.

`double timeDifference = (next.time - curr.time) / (curr.time - previous.time);
previuos.value = (previous.value + curr.value * timeDifference) / 2`

Also I dont want result to be double but long so I need to use rounding that will change distance. Also one minute is about 300 records so i hope that rounding will not effect calculation so much.

Comment: You could use BigDecimal if you need precision, but this will decrease performance, but maybe that doesn't matter for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a list of value pairs, i.e.:

```
    time | speed
1:  0    | 0
2:  300  | 10
3:  600  | 40
4:  900  | 48
5:  1200 | 50
6:  1500 | 30
7:  1800 | 0
```

You always need to look at two values `i` and `i-1`. We start at `i=1` because else we'd access index `-1`:

```
for(int i=1; i<list.size(); i++) {
  if(Math.abs(list.get(i).speed - list.get(i-1).speed) < 3) {
    list.get(i-1).time = (list.get(i).time + list.get(i-1).time) / 2;
    list.get(i-1).speed = (list.get(i).speed + list.get(i-1).speed) / 2;
    list.remove(i);
  }
}
```

**In words:** If the speed difference between `i` and `i-1` is less than 3, then update entry `i-1` and set its time and speed to average of `i` and `i-1`. Afterwards we remove item `i` from the list.

**What happens to the example data:** This code removes entry `5:` from the example data, because `abs(50-48) = 2` and `2 < 3`, and set entry `4:` to `time = 1150` and `speed = 49`

The example above of course has **at least two** problems (that are easy to fix -- e.g. your homework): **1.** If the list only has a single entry, the code will throw an exception. **2.** After removing an item, the `list.size()` changes, but the code above won't recognize that. This means: After removing any entry, it will throw an exception.

I haven't tested it, it's just to show you how you could clean the list.

You could additionally add some code, that prevents removing the last entry from the list, because else you likely won't have the exact last time value. It's also possible to run this many times on the same data, until the `list.size()` stays constant.

(have a look at the comments below)

Comment: While I find this to be a good solution, I have a question: why just `3`? I mean, is it a parameter, or is there a statistically valid way to calculate it, based on the available data?

Comment: `3` because I felt like `3` ;-) You can replace the `if` condition with everything you like. You could also calculate the difference between both values in percent and then look if it's smaller than 20% or whatever you like. The code should just show, how to compare two values from a list, calculate and set the average and remove one entry. (Btw: `speed` and `3` can't have any relevance, because no one knows if it's km/h, mp/h or seamiles per second, or or or ... )

Comment: And my solution is pretty bad, there are lot's of cases that it won't detect and it may produce bad data. **1.** In the example, it will delete the max. speed, which may be important. **2.** When the speed entries are something like `0, 1, 2, 1, 0` the result will be `0.5625`, which is totally meaningless. **3.** It would be much better to detect when acceleration goes up or down, and then keep the max and min values, i.e.: `0, 2, 0`. That data has much more information! Of course this makes the algorithm way more complicated.

Comment: Thanks for reply and I think I made it little bit misleading. I was asking if there is any complex algorithm for this, something like genetic algorithm. But your answer is good nought but i will need to do some changes. Listed in my questing.

Comment: I don't think that there is any generic algorithm. There are too many options and possible parameters. For this particular case, you need to look at index `i` and `i-1`, but there are for sure cases where you need to look at 3 items (or more) to compute the correct result. Then (as explained in the comment above) you might to refuse to change particular items, like first one, last one, or the max. / min. values, etc.

Comment: Thanks like this i can trim data about 90% of size and lost only 0,1% precision on distance.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to keep any history, you can simply update the traveled distance when new data is retrieved. I don't know how do you do the calculus, I write the first example I can think.

```
Measurement record = null;
double distance = 0;
long totalTime = 0;

// New record handler
public void recordListener(Measurement newRecord) {
    if(record != null) {
        double avgSpeed = (record.speed + newRecord.speed) / 2.0;
        long timeDelta = newRecord.time - record.time;
        distance += avgSpeed * (timeDelta / 1000)   // millis to seconds
        totalTime += timeDelta;
    }
    record = newRecord;
}
```

Comment: I can not do that because data flow is as follows: Collect data -> Trim them -> send them on server -> Calculate distance

Comment: And this flow is executed only once or regularly?